# Include Launcher Icons for xxdpi and xxxhdpi

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Running v0.1.64.

The highest resolution launcher icon included in the app is for xhdpi (320 DPI), while the latest phones such as the Nexus 5 look for the launcher icon in the xxxhdpi (640 DPI) resource folder. Since a high resolution icon is not available, the xhdpi icon is used and upscaled to fit, and looks quite blurry compared to other icons.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: That is a wonderful color scheme, by the way. <uses up noise comment allowance for the day>

Comment: Haha thanks. :) It's one of the stock wallpapers on KitKat. The blue icons stand out really well.

Comment: These will be coming soon. Our awesome designer got the dimensions from me last week but was busy with the new top bar that came out last night since then.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, any word on this? The app seems to be released on the Play store but the icons are hideously small. It would be great if you could fix this. Thx.

Comment: @Mridang The icon looks fine to me. I'm pretty sure this was fixed a long time back but never marked closed.

Comment: Yes, this was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

This was fixed as of 0.1.80. The app now has xxhdpi and xxxhdpi launcher images.

Here's what it looks like now on my Nexus 5 now:

[image]

Comment: This is why I'm a horrible designer: I can't find a difference for the life of me.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel look at the edges of the rectangles :) The ones from this screenshot are more sharp than the ones from the question.

Comment: Alright, I think I see it. I thought it was because of the different background color. cheers!