# Why is the Stack Exchange icon bigger?

Tags: support, android-app

I recently updated the Stack Exchange Android app and noticed the icon became bigger.

[image]

This looks a little weird on my home screen.

Comment: Because Stack Exchange is growing geometrically, like Skynet. Soon all your phone will belong to us.

Comment: Fixed the circle

Comment: Seems like you're getting the [higher resolution version of the icon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207505/include-launcher-icons-for-xxdpi-and-xxxhdpi) that is used on higher resolution devices, and in the Google Experience Launcher. Maybe include what version of Android/ROM you're running, maybe the device and what launcher if it isn't the stock launcher?

Comment: I'm all "WHAT ARE YOU TALKING ABOUT, Precious T.?" because the shortcut icon is totes small on my Moto-X, even though the app has had about 7-8 app updates since I got it.  I dragged the current (smaller) shortcut off my main screen to trash, and created a new shortcut from the entry in the prime application list.  The icon for the newly created shortcut was much larger than the prior one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our feedback from the Google Play team's review of the application included:

> App icon should be a bit larger.

Which was confusing to me at first too, but when I looked at the Android [Design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#launcher) it didn't indicate that the icon should have any padding in its region, which ours did. It was also obvious that our icon was smaller than should be when you put it up next to the icons of some Google made apps like Chrome.

Our new (slightly) bigger icon fills the entire contents of the bounding box for an icon, which makes it look better when displayed next to other applications following the guidelines like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm quite surprised that in android each app can have different sized icon. On my iPhone, all icons are exactly the same size, to the pixel level.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, the icons on Android *are* the "same" size, but many have a transparent padding. IIRC, the *original* design guide said they should have a specific padding area, so many icons still use that. I may just remember it wrong, but I'd *swear* it's been changed since I started developing apps.

Comment: @Geobits weird... guess that's the (small) price you pay for fast-changing environment. :)